# How to make this table scrollable?

Tags: html, scroll, html-table, internet-explorer-8

In IE8 it doesn't have the scroll... how can I make my result table scrollable?

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="sso" value="<?php echo $exec->fields['hrOracleNumber']; ?>" onclick="selectSSO(this.value);"></td>
    <td><font color="336699" face="Helvetica" size="1px" ><?php echo $exec->fields['hrOracleNumber']; ?></font></td>
    <td><font color="336699" face="Helvetica" size="1px" ><?php echo $exec->fields['firstName']; ?></font></td>
    <td><font color="336699" face="Helvetica" size="1px" ><?php echo $exec->fields['lastName']; ?></font></td>
    <td><font color="336699" face="Helvetica" size="1px" ><?php echo $exec->fields['description']; ?></font></td>
</tr>

<?php 

    $exec->MoveNext();
} ?>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Does it scroll on the other browsers? Are you using the window scroll, of have you defined one using CSS? Why are you showing your PHP code since this is 100% on the client?

Comment: Is the last part of a code, I'm sorry I dind't take away the php part, and yes at least in chrome it does.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you would need more rows to scroll vertically.

But to make the table scroll you would wrap it in a div tag and apply CSS styling to that div by adding a fixed height and set the overflow to auto.

The html would look like this:

```
<div class="scroll-table">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="sso" value=""></td>
    <td><font color="336699" face="Helvetica" size="1px" >Test</font></td>
    <td><font color="336699" face="Helvetica" size="1px" >Test</font></td>
    <td><font color="336699" face="Helvetica" size="1px" >Test</font></td>
    <td><font color="336699" face="Helvetica" size="1px" >Test</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The CSS style sheet would look like this:

```
   .scroll-table{
       height: 50px;
       overflow: auto;
    }
```

IE 8 doesn't support overflow-x or overflow-y, so you might want to specify a width as well because overflow auto will allow scrolling in both directions.